# How to convert Java custom object list to JSON array?

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC app. I need to get list of LocationModel class objects in JSON, using AJAX. Following is my LocationModel class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name="Location")
public class LocationModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="locationid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int locationId;

    @Column(name="locationname")
    private String locationName;

    @Column(name="locationdesc")
    private String locationDescription;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String locationType;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="district")
    private String district;

    @Column(name="lattitude")
    private String lattitude;

    @Column(name="longitude")
    private String longitude;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }

    public void setLattitude(String lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLocationType() {
        return locationType;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public void setLocationType(String locationType) {
        this.locationType = locationType;
    }

    public int getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(int locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }

    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }

    public String getLocationDescription() {
        return locationDescription;
    }

    public void setLocationDescription(String locationDescription) {
        this.locationDescription = locationDescription;
    }
}
```

Below is ajax block in a jsp page.

```
function locationList(){

    var locationName = jQuery('#locationName').val();
    var json = {"name" : locationName};  
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<c:url value="/contact/ajax" />',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        cache:false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success:function(response){
            alert("Validation: "+response.validation+"   Name: "+response.name+"  Location: "+response.location);
        },
        error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

How can we pass data to controller from AJAX and how can we get list of LocationModel objects in json and parse? I have searched many places, but not able to find answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.** Its
>   external form is a string wrapped in curly braces with colons between
>   the names and values, and commas between the values and names. The
>   internal form is an object having get() and opt() methods for
>   accessing the values by name, and put() methods for adding or
>   replacing values by name. The values can be any of these types:
>   Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, and String, or the
>   JSONObject.NULL object.

[JSONObject Documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

`public JSONObject() // Construct an empty JSONObject.`

You can also check out [Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data Rest, look:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/